# kafka jdbc sink connector throws org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException (Struct schema's field name not specified properly) to insert PG table

Tags: json, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am using kafka-jdbc-sink-connector for my project where I need to post some JSON at kafka topic (kafka_subs) and then by using jdbc-sink-connector, I need to insert that record at the postgres table(subs) under schema (TESTDB). But I am getting the below exception.

Kafka connector version is,
*confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:latest*

And I am running Kafka connector from docker compose,

Below is the jdbc sink connector configuration,

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8082/connectors -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
        "name": "jdbc_sink_postgres_022",
        "config": {
                "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
                "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres",
                "connection.user": "postgres",
                "connection.password": "postgres",
                "topics": "kafka_subs",
                "auto.create": "true",
                "insert.mode":"insert",
                "table.name.format": "TESTDB.subs",
                "mode":"bulk",
                "pk.mode":"none",
                "poll.interval.ms": 60000,
                "pk.mofr":"bulk",
        "value.converter.schema.enable":"true",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
            "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter ",
            "schemas.enable":"true"
                }
        }'
```

This is the record I am posting at kafka topic, using ./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh,

```
{
    "schema": {
        "type": "struct",
        "name": "TESTDB",
        "optional": false,
        "fields": [{
                "name": "sub_id",
                "optional": false,
                "type": "string"
            }, {
                "name": "sub_name",
                "optional": false,
                "type": "string"
            }
        ]
    },
    "payload": {
        "sub_id": "10000",
        "sub_name": "Sssss"
    }
}
```

Below is the exception,

```
[2021-09-09 16:18:36,705] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=jdbc_sink_postgres_022-0} Error converting message value in topic 'kafka_subs' partition 0 at offset 0 and timestamp 1631204315678: Struct schema's field name not specified properly (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Struct schema's field name not specified properly
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.asConnectSchema(JsonConverter.java:534)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:382)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.toConnectData(Converter.java:87)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertValue(WorkerSinkTask.java:545)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$1(WorkerSinkTask.java:501)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:190)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:132)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:501)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:478)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:328)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:232)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:201)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:189)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:238)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[2021-09-09 16:18:36,707] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=jdbc_sink_postgres_022-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:206)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:132)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:501)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:478)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:328)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:232)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:201)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:189)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:238)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Or how to insert this simple json at postgres table?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This problem is now solved for me as I have changed the "name" under "fields" to "field", now with this change, it is working fine,

Previous json was:

```
{
    "schema": {
        "type": "struct",
        "name": "TESTDB",
        "optional": false,
        "fields": [{
                "name": "sub_id",
                "optional": false,
                "type": "string"
            }, {
                "name": "sub_name",
                "optional": false,
                "type": "string"
            }
        ]
    },
    "payload": {
        "sub_id": "10000",
        "sub_name": "Sssss"
    }
}
```

changed json is:

```
{
    "schema": {
        "type": "struct",
        "name": "TESTDB",
        "optional": false,
        "fields": [{
                "field": "sub_id",
                "optional": false,
                "type": "string"
            }, {
                "field": "sub_name",
                "optional": false,
                "type": "string"
            }
        ]
    },
    "payload": {
        "sub_id": "10001",
        "sub_name": "Ggggg"
    }
}
```